# Color navigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, colors, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I got a **problem** when i change **dynamically** the **color** of my `navigationbar`. I would like get my `navigationbar` like the second screenShot.

any help would be appreciated :)

**This is my code:**

```
 self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(76/255.0) green:(170/255.0) blue:(255/255.0) alpha:1.0];
```

**The result:**

[image]

**what i would like:**

[image]

Comment: Just set for ios7 [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];

Comment: Write Like this Change Value according to you...self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:215.0f/255.0f green:215.0f/255.0f blue:215.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it ...

```
      self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:215.0f/255.0f green:215.0f/255.0f blue:215.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
```

For iOS > 7

```
   self.navigationBar.barTintColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:215.0f/255.0f green:215.0f/255.0f blue:215.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
   self.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
   self.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

Comment: it's become white when i set `[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];`

Comment: `[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(76.0f/255.0) green:(170.0f/255.0) blue:(255.0f/255.0) alpha:1.0f];`

Comment: try this....self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:215.0f/255.0f green:215.0f/255.0f blue:215.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];

Comment: no work too even with `self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];` always white

Comment: i don't use any image on the navigationbar

Comment: it's work the background change to red but why tintColor ? it's not for the Text ?

Comment: if you want to change toyr text color also then use self.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

Answer (score 1):

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imgNavigationbar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your code as follows and try:

```
 self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(76.0f/255.0) green:(170.0f/255.0) blue:(255.0f/255.0) alpha:1.0f];
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing color, replace it by an image.

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)customizeUserInterface
{
    if (IOS_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0"))
    {
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    } else
    {
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    }
}
```